# Vue how to access props of parent component - the importer not a wrapper

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**Overall goal:** from a child Vue component, get access to the component *that it is imported and used within* - which is not always the same as `$parent`. This should be done by only making changes within the child component (if possible).

We have `PinButton` Vue component meant to add a "pinning" functionality to other components. This component is used within many other components and we want to be able to access the parent props so they can be saved and rendered on a different page of "pinned content" by passing those props back into the parent component.

Note: I know this would be possible by manually passing the parent props down into the component (`<pin-button :parent-props="$props" />`), but we're trying to avoid having to do this every time the component is used.

A minimal reproduction of this with a single parent and child component will show that you can access parent props using `$parent.$props`. However, when the child component is nested as slot content of some other component within the parent, then the child will get the props of the wrapper component - not the component in which it is imported and actually used.

[Sandbox reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-access-parent-props-6mbu4?file=/src/components/ParentComponent.vue) - I want to get the props for `ParentComponent` from within `ChildComponent`. The expected value is shown by passing the props along (what I'm trying to avoid) and the actual value is the props of the `SlotWrapper` component, which doesn't import `ChildComponent` so I wouldn't consider it the true parent, but it is the direct parent element in the `<template>`

> Update:
> Seems like the [suggested solution](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Parent-Component-Instance) for "arbitrarily deep" access is [provide/inject](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Dependency-Injection), but this would still seem to require changing all components that use the `<pin-button />`

Comment: `provide/inject`, events or a global store (Vuex) are the usual ways you might approach passing data between arbitrarily deep components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can access ParentComponent from ChildComponent via the "context" the component is rendered within:

```js
// ChildComponent.vue
computed: {
  expectedProps() {
    return this.$vnode.context.$props
  }
}
```

But this might be an ["XY"](https://xyproblem.info/) kind of problem; I'm sure there's a better design solution for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you! Updated the sandbox and that works perfectly. I'd agree this is a symptom rather than a root cause. We're partway through refactoring the usage of the parent components to consistently implement the pin component in a single place, but it's currently still strewn about so I was looking for something that works as-is and as we continue with the refactor.